# Handling multipart/batch request in WCF Service

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, multipart

Has anyone ever implemented batching support on top of WCF Service(not WCF data service) using  HTTP multipart requests? I was looking over internet an found a tutorial over how to do the same in WebAPI and WCF Data Service but not on how to do the same in WCF Service. Any suggestion or references.

Also, if there is no in build support to do the same then how to construct the multipart response in the azure web role and what should be the return type of the request handler function?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the messageEncoding property in the wsHttpBinding.  You will want to use MTOM as your encoder for this scenario.  Here is an example from the SDK.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395209(v=vs.110).aspx